# Integral tends to $0$ as $R$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial of degree less than or equals to 2. Let $C(0;R)$ be the circle with center 0 and radius $R$ traversed anti clockwise. Show that if $C(0;R)$ encloses $u,a,b$, then $$\lim\limits_{R \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0;R)}\dfrac{P(z)}{(z-a)^{2}(z-u)(z-b)}dz = 0$$

After finishing the question, i think i don't fully understand the concepts anymore, Does the end result of this question actually mean $$\int_{C(0;R)}\dfrac{P(z)}{(z-a)^{2}(z-u)(z-b)}dz = 0$$ when $R$ is very large?

Let us call this function $\dfrac{P(z)}{(z-a)^{2}(z-u)(z-b)}$ to be $f(z)$.

From what i learnt so far, questions like these need us to apply the Cauchy integral formula and mostly the end results is not 0!!! Although i did not go and manually compute by hand what the integral of $C$ for this question is, my approach would be simply identify the "bad points" in where the function $f(z)$ is not analytic on, in this case after simple factorizing we have the bad points to be at $z = a,u,b$,all of them are contained in the circle. Hence i just construct three small circles around the points and we have $\int_{C}f(z)dz = \int_{C1}f(z)dz + \int_{C2}f(z)dz +\int_{C3}f(z)dz$ and now i apply Cauchy Integral individually to C1 and C2 and C3 to do. And do note most of the times the answer DOES NOT EQUAL to 0.

What i am confused is i have seen similar questions saying as $R$ (the radius) tends to infinity, the integral tends to 0, suggesting Cauchy Goursat theorem applies even when there are bad points inside.

One thing i found out when i read up is the Extended Cauchy Goursat Theorem, saying that "let $f$ be **continuous** on $D$ and be analytic on $D-{z_0}$ then we still have $\int_{C}fdz =0$ for all closed curve in $D$."

However, we have seen that $f$ is not continuous on the points mentioned earlier.

Comment: I think you're mixing two things: you probably want to integrate the function over some interval or path (e.g. the real integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?) and you do this by calculating a complex integral over a _closed path_, such as a semi-circle with base on the real axis and a radius $R$ you'll let tend to infinity. The integral over the circular part will tend to $0$ as $R \to \infty$, but that doesn't mean the integral over the entire (closed!) path is 0...

Comment: Yes the residue theorem regards closed and simple Jordan curves. So you need to close the endpoints to the half circle -R and +R to get a Jordan curve, check which poles are inside et.c.

Comment: @mathreadler  i have edited the question so that i am actually integrating over a closed contour!

Comment: @StackTD  i have edited the question so that i am actually integrating over a closed contour!

Comment: The _'integral goes to 0 as $R \to \infty$'_-argument applies to the part of the large semi-circle **only**, not to the other parts of your closed path such as the small semi-circles around the poles. The integral, computed as a sum of different contributions, can of course be non-zero.